# All declarations of 'size' , 'prototype' must have identical modifiers

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have downloaded code from repository and run it on local getting these errors
[image: error screen shot]

have following versions [image: version detail]
when i run ionic serve got there someone please help me

Comment: What is your npm version ? and have you run install command ?

Comment: my npm version is 4.2.0 shown in figure @RasikhMashhadi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the typings.json and typings folder from your project and run. it should solve this problem.

```
npm install @types/lodash --save-dev --save-exact
```

Delete the typings.json file, and the typings directory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was `@types/es6-shim`

I uninstalled it (`npm uninstall @types/es6-shim`) and everything worked!